# Inserting dict objects from a list with key-value pairs to a new list

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a `dict` called `data`, it has one `key` called `clubs` that maps to a `list` which contains `dict` objects. I would like to add every object from the `clubs` `list` to a new `list`.

I could loop through the `list` and create a new one, however the `arr` contains only the `key` names of the `dict` object. How can I add the whole dict objects to my new list, not just the key names? Basically I want the list that is inside the `clubs` dict.

This is how my `arr` list looks:

```
['key1', 'key2', 'key1', 'key2', 'key1', 'key2', 'key1', key2]
```

And here is my implementation:

```
arr = []

for item in data['clubs']:

    arr.extend(item)

print (len(arr))

print (arr)
```

I don't understand why I get just strings (key names), In Objective-c it would work.( `data['clubs']` would be a `list`, `item` is a `dict` obj from the `list` that I add to a new `list` called `arr`. )

And here is how the raw (json) data looks:

```
{ "clubs": [
    {
        "location": "Dallas",
        "id": "013325K52",
        "type": "bar"
    },

    {
        "location": "Dallas",
        "id": "763825X56",
        "type": "restaurant"
    }
] }
```

And I would like something like this:

```
{
    "location": "Dallas",
    "id": "013325K52",
    "type": "bar"
},

{
    "location": "Dallas",
    "id": "763825X56",
    "type": "restaurant"
}
```

Comment: Please show us a representative sample of `data`, and what `arr` should look like

Comment: @inspectorG4dget I added it.

Comment: what should `arr` look like?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget sorry, just added it now.

Comment: Use `arr,append` instead of `arr.extend`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr.extend(item)` will try to interpret `item` as a `sequence`, and add all the items in that sequence to `arr`. To add a single element, use `append`.

```
arr = []
for item in data['clubs']:
    arr.append(item)
print(arr)
```

However, you could just write:

```
print(list(data['clubs']))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is already a key/value pair where the value is a python `list`. To extract this in to its own list, you simply assign from the key:

```
arr = data['clubs']   # returns the list associated with this key!
```

An alternative which may be more useful if you need to do any additional processing of the items in the list/dict:

```
arr = [{}]* len(data['clubs'])
for k, v in enumerate(data['clubs']):
    arr[k] = v

print(arr)
```

Should result with:

```
[
{'type': 'bar', 
  'location': 'Dallas', 
  'id': '013325K52'}, 
 {'type': 'restaurant', 
  'location': 'Dallas', 
  'id': '763825X56'}
]
```